# Split column value into substrings and search for pattern in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table like this:

| campaign | code |
| --- | --- |
| AL2330GH_HDKASL_QCLKP | NULL |
| JPDJK34_QPKSLL_QKPAL | NULL |
| QCK32_SDSKDS_TLLKA | NULL |

I want to update the above table by populating the column 'code' with a substring in column 'campaign' which starts with 'AL', 'QC', or 'QP'. All the column values have 3 substrings separated by an '_'. If none of the substrings matches with the provided values, then keep the 'code' column value as NULL. And if multiple matches happen, take the first substring.

**Desired Output:**

| campaign | code |
| --- | --- |
| AL2330GH_HDKASL_QCLKP | AL2330GH |
| JPDJK34_QPKSLL_QKPAL | QPKSLL |
| QCK32_SDSKDS_TLLKA | QCK32 |

**Link to try out the problem:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8qoFDL1RmjwpwFNP3LP4eK/1

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: MS SQL Server has the following versions: 2019, 2017, 2016, 2014, 2012, etc.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky MS SQL Server 2017.

Comment: If all of the columns have the exact same number of substrings, this really begs the question, why don't you fix the design so that the substrings (which clearly have independent and hierarchical meaning) are stored in three separate columns? As you can see from the answers, it is much easier to assemble a string than it is to break it apart.

Comment: All clarifications (such as the server version) should be [edit]ed into to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [sample code guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), not left as [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) or [linked](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using `OPENJSON()`:

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT campaign, value, code, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY campaign ORDER BY [key])
  FROM
  (
    SELECT campaign, [key], value, code
    FROM dbo.SomeTable 
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["',
      REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(campaign,'JSON'),'_','","'),'"]')) AS j
  ) AS x WHERE LEFT(value,2) IN ('AL','QC','QP')
)
UPDATE src SET code = value WHERE rn = 1;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd5e2592ec88d681627c4c140825902b)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XML and XQuery for tokenization. XML/XQuery data model is based on *ordered sequences*. Exactly what we need for the scenario.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, campaign varchar(50), code varchar(20));
INSERT INTO @tbl (campaign, code) VALUES
('AL2330GH_HDKASL_QCLKP', NULL),
('JPDJK34_QPKSLL_QKPAL', NULL),
('QCK32_SDSKDS_TLLKA', NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '_';

UPDATE t
SET code = c.query('
    for $x in /root/r[substring(text()[1],1,2)=("AL","QC","QP")]
    return $x').value('(/r/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(campaign, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------+----------+
| id |       campaign        |   Code   |
+----+-----------------------+----------+
|  1 | AL2330GH_HDKASL_QCLKP | AL2330GH |
|  2 | JPDJK34_QPKSLL_QKPAL  | QPKSLL   |
|  3 | QCK32_SDSKDS_TLLKA    | QCK32    |
+----+-----------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `STRING_SPLIT` with `CROSS APPLY` and `ROW_NUMBER` window function to make it.

`CHARINDEX` function will find the first match position value then we can put the split value in the first parameter,  then we can find which string the first appearance.

```
SELECT campaign,value
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY campaign ORDER BY CHARINDEX(v.value,t1.campaign)) rn 
    FROM  mainTable t1
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t1.campaign,'_') v
    WHERE (value LIKE 'AL%'
    OR value LIKE 'QC%'
    OR value LIKE 'QP%')
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you want to `UPDATE` values you can try `UPDATE` like this.

```
UPDATE t1
SET
    code = value
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY campaign ORDER BY CHARINDEX(v.value,t1.campaign)) rn 
    FROM  mainTable t1
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t1.campaign,'_') v
    WHERE (value LIKE 'AL%'
    OR value LIKE 'QC%'
    OR value LIKE 'QP%')
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=276750f4539142cfa203aec4868ba318)

Comment: Unfortunately, the `STRING_SPLIT(()` function doesn't guarantee sequential order after splitting. Just the upcoming not released yet SQL Server 2022 does that.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I know so that way I am using `Row_number` window function with `CHARINDEX` instead

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() will follow the unpredictable STRING_SPLIT(() produced set, i.e. it is too late for the order. The CHARINDEX() function cannot be used. It should be a natural order.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I think `CHARINDEX(v.value,t1.campaign)` which might represent the order 

here is a sample https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=80e822a298c413ba992f64d9ffadaea0

Comment: `CHARINDEX` function will find the first match position value then we can put the split value in the first parameter,  then we can find which string first appearance.